# Results duplicate each time the first row is clicked

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm currently practicing ASP via C# by creating a fictional shop.

The issue lies within the basket as whenever the first row is clicked (for row deletion), the entire select query executes again and appends to the existing results.

This has no impact on the database, and other rows that are clicked function correctly.

The value of the row (productid) is hidden in a form and gets submitted via GET, and is retrieved on another page, which deletes basket data associated with the submitted ID.

**Shopping Basket Page**

```
// #### SELECT ALL ITEMS THAT HAVE BEEN ORDERED BY THE USER #####
           queryStr = @"SELECT products.ProductImage, products.ProductName,products.ProductDesc,products.ProductPrice,purchase.ProductID, purchase.Quantity 
    FROM products, purchase
    WHERE purchase.UserID=?uid AND purchase.ProductID = products.ProductID";

            cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?uid", uid);



            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           // pname = "";



            while (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
            {

                prodid = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductID"));
                pimg = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductImage"));
                pname = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductName"));
                desc = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductDesc"));
                price = reader.GetFloat(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductPrice"));

                if (Session["uname"] != null)
                {
                    output.InnerHtml += "<tr runat='server'><td><img src='" + pimg + "'></td><td>" + pname + "</td><td>" + desc + "</td><td>£" + price +
                        "</td><td>  <form runat='server' action='removebasketitem.aspx' method='get'><input type='hidden' ID='registerButton' runat='server' name='remove' value='" + prodid + "' /><input type='submit' ID='registerButton' runat='server' value='Remove' /></form></td></tr>";
                }
                else
                {
                Response.Redirect("index.aspx", false);
            }
```

**Remove Basket Item Page**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int prod = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["remove"]);
        int uid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"]);



        String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();

        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();

        queryStr = "";

        queryStr = "DELETE FROM purchase WHERE ProductID=?prod";

        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?uid", uid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?prod", prod);
        cmd.ExecuteReader();

        conn.Close();



        Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());


    }
```

After deleting, it re-directs back to the previous page. Does anybody have any idea as to why the first row reacts in such a way when the remaining rows work?
[image]

Comment: Page_Load runs on every postback. If you want to not run code on a postback, check for that condition. `if (!IsPostBack) { /* run code here */ }`. By the way, if you're learning ASP.NET for the first time, why are you learning Web Forms? Web Forms is an old dinosaur and dying a slow and just death. You should learn ASP.NET MVC, or a client side framework that talks to a server side API.

Comment: The post-back has prevented the duplication, however the deletion situation remains the same in regards to the first record not doing anything.  MVC shall be my next chapter :)